# Меню контакты в Ios

Tags: ios

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, в любой программе чата для ios (ВК, WhatsApp, Telegram) в разделе контакты выводится список имеющихся контактов. При прокручивании этого списка в разделители сменяют друг-друга при переходе от одной буквы в контакте, к другой.

Как это делается? 
Или это стандартная фича?

Буду очень признателен за ответ. Не судите строго...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прилипающие разделители секций — стандартная функция UITableView и UICollectionView.
Задается методом DataSource.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Одним вопросом меньше. Вы случайно не знаете инструментов, как это эмитировать на других платформах, скажем с использованием ionic или подобных фреймворков?